# How can I write a .NET console application to access SkyDrive?

Tags: .net, onedrive

I'm trying to work out how to create a simple .NET console application to access skydrive so I can send and receive files from a command line.

The Live Connect SDK and documentation appears to be a little vague and generally targeted at Metro or HTML apps.

If someone knows how to authenticate and then list the contents, which I think should be simple, then the rest will probably be easy.

Ideally I would like to use an API, but if I have to revert to driving the REST API, that is ok as well.

Here's a block of code I'm trying to use

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Live;

namespace SkyDriveCmd
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var task = Run();
                task.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        private static async Task Run()
        {
            var auth = new LiveAuthClient("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            var client = new LiveConnectClient(auth.Session);
            var result = await client.GetAsync("/");
            Console.WriteLine(result.RawResult);
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is wrong as auth.Session is null, but I'm finding a massive lack of documentation around how this could work.

Comment: You could just cheat.  Install the Skydrive client then use normal File I/O operations on those folders.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have code you can show us, it's impossible to imagine your code.

Comment: @Nick Randell check this question it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112617/upload-file-to-skydrive-through-skydrive-api

Comment: I've added an example that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using an Api downloaded from http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/releases/view/103081

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new SkyDriveServiceClient();

        client.LogOn("YourEmail@hotmail.com", "password");
        WebFolderInfo wfInfo = new WebFolderInfo();

        WebFolderInfo[] wfInfoArray = client.ListRootWebFolders();

        wfInfo = wfInfoArray[0];
        client.Timeout = 1000000000;

        string fn = @"test.txt";
        if (File.Exists(fn))
        {
            client.UploadWebFile(fn, wfInfo);
        }

    }
```