# How to Sync a file with SkyDrive for Windows Store apps?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, onedrive

I have a simple text file that holds some data and I am looking for some information on how can a user sync that file with SkyDrive ?

This is for a Windows Store 8 application. I haven't found a tutorial on how to integrate SkyDrive with my app (using C#).

Any information is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826531#uploading_files) docs on MSDN have some helpful information. Not entirely sure that's what you're going for, but it at least handles uploading. There's some more information in [Upload file to skydrive through SkyDrive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112617/upload-file-to-skydrive-through-skydrive-api) as well.