# upload files to skydrive

Tags: asp.net, onedrive

I've been doing some research on how to upload files into SkyDrive using ASP.Net web forms, and I can't find useful links. Can you guys give some links on tutorials, or give me some tutorials on how to do it.

Comment: You can use SKY Drive API.

Refer below link :-

[Upload file to skydrive through SkyDrive API][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112617/upload-file-to-skydrive-through-skydrive-api

Comment: You can't have researched very well, I found lots of good resources and several right here on SO on my first search. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112617/upload-file-to-skydrive-through-skydrive-api

Comment: can you please give me the link for the skydrive api? thanks :)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below link for reference.
Download sdk here, sample also there......
http://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/

SkyDrive API documentation link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/live/hh826521

Comment: how can i integrate this API on my asp.net projecT?