# How to upload file to OneDrive through console app?

Tags: c#, file-upload, console-application, onedrive

I am trying to upload a file to [OneDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/onedrive) from within console app. After digging a bit into Google I found [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631819.aspx) but I couldn't find any article demonstrating file upload step by step using [Live SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631819.aspx). Is there any good resource explaining how to it? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12112617/upload-file-to-skydrive-through-skydrive-api

Comment: I tried to use [SkyDrive Api](https://skydriveapiclient.codeplex.com/)  but it didn't worked at all. It gives strange exceptions. I've gone through some code snippets demonstrating how to Live SDK to upload file but it seems that these codes will work for Windows Phone and not for console app since there is no username and password in those codes.

Answer (score 4):

The LiveSDK has a number of examples and template code that are hosted on Github, https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows.

To see an example of how uploading is down you can explore the sample applications located at https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows/blob/master/src/Desktop/Samples/ApiExplorer/MainForm.cs#L259

Here is a  snippet from the ApiExplorer example application:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog(); 
Stream stream = null; 
dialog.RestoreDirectory = true; 


if (dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) 
{ 
    throw new InvalidOperationException("No file is picked to upload."); 
} 
try 
{ 
    if ((stream = dialog.OpenFile()) == null) 
    { 
        throw new Exception("Unable to open the file selected to upload."); 
    }
    using (stream) 
    { 
        return await this.liveConnectClient.UploadAsync(path, dialog.SafeFileName, stream, OverwriteOption.DoNotOverwrite); 
    } 
} 
catch (Exception ex) 
{ 
    throw ex; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid user interaction completely, and still to use onedrive api in your console application you will have to implement custom logic.

First you need to mark your Main method as [STAThread] (single thread apartment module):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)     
{
 //...
}
```

After that create the **WebBrowser** control at runtime (you will need WinForms reference for that).

Add **DocumentCompleted** event to WebBrowser, and there inject your JavaScript in order to automatically fill login form and simulate login button click, and within the same method check if the WebBrowser url is your ReturnUrl. If it is then parse authorization code, and proceed to get access and refresh token.

```
setInterval(function(){
    //your code to interact with ui
}, 1000);
```

Don't forget to put some code blocker like:

```
while (!_autoLoginCompleted)
{
    Application.DoEvents();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Navigate to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize with appropriate parameters (clientId, returnUrl) to trigger DocumentCompleted event.

After that you can store these tokens and use them later, and periodically refresh them.

You might also need to suppress JS exceptions.

BTW, one interesting thing is with all their code samples that they are not saying that you don't need to specify Client Secret if you are using native (console) app.