# Upload file to a user onedrive api

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to let admin upload files  to a separate user, my code looks like:

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Uses\Codey\1kb.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    DriveItem uploadedItem = await 
        GraphClient.Users["someuser@codey.onmicrosoft.com"]
            .Drive
            .Root
            .ItemWithPath(fName)
            .Content
            .Request()
            .PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
}
```

but this returns:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: itemNotFound
>
> Message: The resource could not be found.

Note: I succceded to let admin upload to himeself(or user to himself) using th API

[Upload or replace the contents of a DriveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Have you looked at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640287/how-to-upload-file-to-onedrive-through-console-app

Comment: @EdneyHolder I don't think the link helps, I'm using Microsoft Graph SDK, the link does't deals with uploading to other user :\

Comment: **Pro tip:** try to avoid _chained methods_ such as this with `multiple indexers` because it makes it difficult to know _which is the offending line_.  i.e. is it the user or file that failed?

Comment: After I followed the steps [Here](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-access-someone-elses-onedrive-account/) it worked